# How to change from which argument is the type inferred in generic methods?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, type-inference, linq-expressions

Suppose there's a static method in my Utils class, that sets the value of a property.

```
public static SetPropertyValue<TDest, TVal>
    (Expression<Func<TDest, TVal>> expression, 
     TDest destination, 
     TVal value) 
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Additionally, there is a class:

```
public class DataObject { public short Code { get; set; } }
```

And the usage code:

```
DataObject obj = new DataObject();
int code = 404;
Utils.SetPropertyValue(m => m.Code, obj, code);
```

When the above code is run, the expression is changed to `m => Convert(m.Code)` because the third parameter given is an **integer** and the expression expects the **short**. That means that the type inference system decided to prefer the third argument to determine the `TVal` type.

I wish this method's **third argument (value)** to be restricted to the type defined by the **first argument (expression)**. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't affect type inference that way - and if it *did* infer `TVal` as `short`, your code wouldn't compile, because there's no implicit conversion from `int` to `short`.

Surely the best solution is just to avoid using two different types to start with:

```
short code = 404;
Utils.SetPropertyValue(m => m.Code, obj, code);
```

Now the types will be inferred properly, and there won't be any conversions.

Comment: Thanks, Jon! But the problem I have with this is the fact that the compiler will allow you to insert an "invalid" type, but silently convert my lambda. Why does it do that?

Comment: @KornelijePetak: Why wouldn't it? The type of `m.Code` is `short`, and that's implicitly convertible to `int`. For example, you could write a method: `public int GetCode(DataObject m) { return m.Code; }` - and that's basically what the compiler is thinking of when it sees the lambda expression. Again - think about why you *wouldn't* expect that to compile...

Comment: @KornelijePetak - this is because you're using a particular *abuse* of the expression system to try to identify a property on an object. The system was never *designed* for you to be able to use an expression to identify properties. The C# compiler has no way to infer that despite you passing an expression that accesses the getter of the property, the code within `SetPropertyValue` is actually planning to access the setter.

Comment: @JonSkeet  You are right. But regarding your comment about not compiling if it were the other way around - I would expect it to work that way, so that user CAN'T provide a value of a different type. But I suppose I could split this method into two, where one would first determine the expression type, and then value could be set. Requires the change of my API, but it would work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @KornelijePetak: The reason it's not working the way you want it to is precisely related to Damien's point - you're specifying a "getter" property and a value. If you specified a *setter* instead (an `Action<TDest, TVal>`) and used a lambda expression of `(m, value) => m.Code = value` then it would fail to compile as you expected, in the same way that you couldn't write `public void SetCode(DataObject m, int code) { m.Code = code; }`. It's the difference between getting data *out* and then implicitly converting it with a widening conversion, and putting data *in*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't know what the expression system was designed for, but I don't find this usage to be the abuse. Then Entity Framework would be a mighty abuser. I am not sure you are right (but I am not sure that I am right either), but I don't think that passing the property as an Expression targets either of its accessors, but the property in general because when I receive the Reflection.PropertyInfo, I can do both. Expressions describe, not perform. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Don't bother replying to my previous comment, I realized my error immediately after Jon's comment. :) I actually wanted the setter, so the Action would be more appropriate. Another lesson learned. Yay!

Comment: @KornelijePetak: The expression tree created represents the getter - again, it's the equivalent of the method I showed before. Just try removing the getter from your type, and you'll see if fail to compile. It doesn't refer to the property in general. While the expression does indeed describe rather than performing, it's *describing* calling the getter.

Comment: What if I needed the user to specify the property he wants to use in a XYZ scenario (like EF does with `Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.ID)`, or `db.Users.Include(u => u.UserOptions)`, how would I do that (without resorting to string argument and then getting PropertyInfo by that string)?

Comment: @KornelijePetak: Well those are both legitimately representing getters, IMO. In order to fetch the primary key for an entity, you call that getter... and `Include` is effectively saying "This getter should work". It's a *little* bit specious, but in particular it wouldn't have the sort of issue that you've run across due to using the wrong side of the property.

Comment: @JonSkeet You commented on the examples, but not in context of the question in my comment. I agree that both examples are requesting getters. What would be the right way for the user of my API to specify which property he wants set when something happens. Is that Action<TDest, TVal> the only right way? Is there any way in which user does not have to assign a value, but only specify a property which would I then use as a setter? I don't know if I'm describing my needs clearly.

Comment: @KornelijePetak: Yes, if you want to describe a setter in an expression tree, you'd use a delegate which can represent that setter action, and you can use a lambda expression to create the expression tree. Aside from anything else, that will validate that there *is* a setter.